# Formatting in some blog posts is broken

Tags: bug, status-deferred, blog, blockquote

### Quoted Lists

In blog posts like [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/10/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/), some quoted material has escaped from its blockquote:

[image: bulleted list with no quote format]

And here's the first example from [C'Mon Get Meta!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/28/cmon-get-meta/):

[image: yet another example]

I don't know how many other blog posts are affected. For some of them (like the example above, where I had to look at the [UserVoice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UserVoice#History) archive), it's not very obvious if the list is a quote.

### Links

Some other types of formatting are also broken, such as [the links here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/22/new-per-site-metas/).

### Semicolon

I don't even know how this happened but there are [stray semicolons in "Q&A;"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/24/stack-exchanges-greatest-hits) in that post.

Comment: A semicolon (`;`) escaped [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/24/stack-exchanges-greatest-hits): `Q&A;`. Not just once, but three times (indicating a systematic error).

Comment: This is in our brand design team's backlog, but since it is relatively low-priority and we don't have an estimate for when it'll be worked on, I'm setting the status to [tag:status-deferred].